# jquery upload two files simultaneously

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, filereader

Is it possible to upload a file by passing its URL to `FileReader` method?
The problem is that I have documents placed on two pages - front and back (or side - A and side B - `sa` and `sb`), scanned in images, named `0001sa.jpg`, `0001sb.jpg` etc. I have to visualize parts of them in the browser, and later put their URL-s in database.

If user marks both files, it is easy:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        filelst = input.files;        
        $("#pict_name").val( filelst[0].name);

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {              
            $('#imgPrev').attr('src', e.target.result).css('max-width', '2200px');
            $('#imgPrev').attr('data-zoom-image', e.target.result);
        //  imgPrev is the ID of the div, where I place the preview 
        // of part the image
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        var reader_b = new FileReader();
        reader_b.onload = function (eb) {
            $('#imgPrev1').attr('src', eb.target.result).css('max-width', '2100px');
            $('#imgPrev1').attr('data-zoom-image', eb.target.result);
            //I have to visualize different part of the back of the document
        }
        reader_b.readAsDataURL(input.files[1]);

    }
}
```

But clicking of two files is not convenient for the operators and 
predisposes to errors. If I could use the URL of the back to upload it, it is possible even to separate files in different directories.
Ho can I achieve this, or is `FileReader` not the right method in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload multiple files using Ajax. Try using ajax file upload with jQuery. There are also many jQuery based uploaders available.